# Laravel email an excel file to specific user to download it

Tags: php, laravel, email

i want to send excel to user through mail .
i want to take the file  after exporting to my emails folder and send it

this is my html view file which i receive on my inbox

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Customers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>excel</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

i received it without the excel file

```
public function exportExcel()
    {
        $yDay = Carbon::now()->subDay()->toDateString();
        $customers = Customer::whereDate('created_at', $yDay)->get()->toArray();
        $file_name = $yDay. '_customers_'.time();
        $exF= \Excel::create($file_name, function ($excel) use ($customers) {
            $excel->sheet('sheet name', function ($sheet) use ($customers) {
                $sheet->fromArray($customers);
            });

        })->store('xlsx', storage_path('storage/emails/'));
        $mail_path= base_path().'/storage/emails/';

        Mail::send('toroduro.emails.excel', ['exc'=>$exF], function ($message) use ($mail_path,$exF) {
            $message->to('example@example.com')->subject('Application') 
         ->attach($mail_path,['as'=>$file_name]);
        });
        return back();
    }
```

i believe i should write a img tag within the html that content url of the excel download but i don't know how i should do it

Comment: Not smart to place a email address on a forum.. spambots will find this email address and spam that address

Comment: thanks for your consideration but it's not my real email it's the testing email and spam but i will change it anyways :D

Comment: Annyway do you get anny errors or warnings with this code?

Comment: unfortunately no i dont get any errors it just sends email without the excel file , i think i should put inside my html page a tag with src= to the downloading link but i still can't figure which link to use in src of that img

Comment: is `$exF->store('xlsx', false, true)['full']` is valid file path because function attach needs to have a file path.. with other words the excel file needs to exists on the harddrive before you can use the function attach.

Comment: ->attach($mail_path,['as'=>$file_name]); give me an error : Unable to open file for reading [/var/www/html/toroduro-vbu/storage/emails/]

Comment: seems like you have permission issues..try setting 777 to storage

Comment: it has all permissions